# Preciso retornar este JSON com Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Meu Json:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "data":{
            "name":"Documents",
            "size":"75kb",
            "type":"Folder"
         },
         "children":[
            {
               "data":{
                  "name":"Work",
                  "size":"55kb",
                  "type":"Folder"
               },
               "children":[
                  {
                     "data":{
                        "name":"Expenses.doc",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Document"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "data":{
                        "name":"Resume.doc",
                        "size":"25kb",
                        "type":"Resume"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "data":{
                  "name":"Home",
                  "size":"20kb",
                  "type":"Folder"
               },
               "children":[
                  {
                     "data":{
                        "name":"Invoices",
                        "size":"20kb",
                        "type":"Text"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "data":{
            "name":"Pictures",
            "size":"150kb",
            "type":"Folder"
         },
         "children":[
            {
               "data":{
                  "name":"barcelona.jpg",
                  "size":"90kb",
                  "type":"Picture"
               }
            },
            {
               "data":{
                  "name":"primeui.png",
                  "size":"30kb",
                  "type":"Picture"
               }
            },
            {
               "data":{
                  "name":"optimus.jpg",
                  "size":"30kb",
                  "type":"Picture"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Se poderia ter explicado da onde e como? por exemplo os models que poderiam gerar esse layout já é um bom começo... realmente pergunta não clara!

Answer (score 0):

Oi,

Na sua controle pode retornar usando o response.

Exemplo:

```
$dados = new MinhaModel();
return response()->json($dados->get())
```

Estou implicando que você já tenha models, esteja usando o Eloquent e está tudo referenciado corretamente em sua controller.

Espero ter ajudado.